# Skip persisting of a related entity in Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity "Entity1", that have an OneToOne (one-direction) relation with another entity "Entity2". Entity2 is managed by a different EntityManager.

Here is part of the Entity1:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity2")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Entity2ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
 **/
protected $entity2;
```

Entity2 already exists, Entity1 is a new entity. Here is part of the persisting logic:

```
$obj1 = new Entity1();
$obj1->setEntity2($this->entity2Manager
                        ->getRepository('VendorBunlde:Entity2')
                        ->find($entity2Id));
$this->entity1Manager->persist($obj1);
$this->entity1Manager->flush();
```

I got this error:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'MyBundle\\Entity\\Entity1#entity2' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: VendorBundle\\Entity\\Entity2@0000000008fbb41600007f3bc3681401. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={\"persist\"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'VendorBundle\\Entity\\Entity2#__toString()' to get a clue
```

How can I force Doctrine to skip persisting Entity2 and in the same time keep the relation? I tried "->merge($obj1)" it works but I get null when I call $obj1->getId()?!

Comment: any reason for skipping it?

Comment: 1) It is a read-only object/lookup, no need for persisting.

Comment: 2) If I tried to persist it using "cascade='Persist'", I get 'Base table or view not found: 1146 Table' because Entity2 exists in another database.

Comment: Actually, merge works but for some reason it does not update the id after persisitng!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me: [Using Relationships with Multiple Entity Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463517/using-relationships-with-multiple-entity-managers)

- I removed the relationship between entity1 & entity2.
- Added @PostLoad to load entity2.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [detach](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) method:

> An entity is detached from an EntityManager and thus no longer managed
>   by invoking the EntityManager#detach($entity) method on it or by
>   cascading the detach operation to it. Changes made to the detached
>   entity, if any (including removal of the entity), will not be
>   synchronized to the database after the entity has been detached.

```
$obj1 = new Entity1();
$obj2 = $this->entity2Manager
                        ->getRepository('VendorBunlde:Entity2')
                        ->find($entity2Id);
$obj1->setEntity2($obj2);
$this->entity1Manager->detach($obj2);
$this->entity1Manager->persist($obj1);
$this->entity1Manager->flush();
```

Haven't tried though, please let me know if it works, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, It does not work - same error 'A new entity ...' - Thanks!