# Symfony2 Doctrine DiscriminatorMap two Databases

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine, discriminator

I have two databases in my project.

First database named : `global`
Second database named : `first_db`

*Global* database has a table `Car` and `Moto` and the *first_db* database has tables `Items` , `Bus` and `Ship`.

Below the post you see the annotations of table Items.

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="Items")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap( {
 *      "car" = "Project\ItemBundle\EntityGlobal\Car",
 *      "moto" = "Project\ItemBundle\EntityGlobal\Moto",
 *      "bus" = "Bus",
 *      "ship" = "Ship",
 *  }
 * )
```

When I create query with DQL it  doesn't understand that `car` and `moto` are in the other database. I have found a beta solution if entities `Car` and `Moto` set annotation with this method

```
* @ORM\Table(name="global.Moto")
* @ORM\Table(name="global.Car")
```

On update schema I don't have a problem, but it's not very safe. I know i can write native queries but I am not sure its the optimal way.

**What is one better way to do this not using native queries?**

Answer (score 0):

In a basic setup from Symfony you are only using 1 database, which is defined in the parameters.yml. Using a second database is possible, but makes everything more complex

Using multiple databases (connections) can be setup like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

But connecting different entities from different databases (connections) is not possible, see this answer: [Using Relationships with Multiple Entity Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463517/using-relationships-with-multiple-entity-managers)

I suggest you strongly look at merging your tables into one database, to make your life a lot easier.