# Symfony/Doctrine - Is it possible to have two tables with the same name in different schema in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to have two tables with the same name in different schema in MSSQL?

For example ***dbo.tableX dbo2.tableX*** ?

If I try it in console doctrine:schema:validate, I get exception "Table with name DB.tableX already exists". It looks as if Doctrine is ignoring database schema.

Each entity is declared by annotation like `"@ORM\Table(name="tableX", schema="dbo")"`. I also try `"@ORM\Table(name="dbo.TableX")"`, but without success

In production it runs fine, but I cannot build new entities from database...

Comment: are you using 2 different entity manager?

Comment: It runs fine in Symfony, but i have problem only when generating entities in console - doctrine:schema:validate generate, etc...

Comment: @FilipŠtencl: Have you tried explicitely selecting an entity manager with the `--em` option?

Comment: I didnt know it. I am trying now command doctrine:schema:validate --em "default"(because I dont have other) and i get the same error...

"default" is string in config.yml in orm param

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have separate schema, you have 2 configure different entityManager as defined here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                        alias: Main
            customer:
                connection: customer
                mappings:
                    Customer:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Customer'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Customer'
                        alias: Customer
```

Note that it's easier to separate your entity betweens 2 different bundles. (If you are using 2 different schema your entities are most likely very independant)

Comment: and can I make associate maps between two EM? onetomany/manytoone?

Comment: No, you can see this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463517/using-relationships-with-multiple-entity-managers

Answer (score -1):

This must be a limitation in doctrine.

You can successfully try this with MS SQL Management Studio:

```
create table dbo.MyTable (t1 int not null primary key);
create schema dbo2;
create table dbo2.MyTable (t1 int not null primary key);
```

So yes, it's absolutely possible to have two (distinct) tables with the same names in separate schemas.

Comment: Yes, I know that it this is possible to have two tables in MSSQL. It must be some Doctrine limitation as you wrote. I use Symfony 2.7 with doctrine 2.5

Comment: @Filip: Please re-read your own post. Your question was "Is it possible to have two tables with the same name in different schema in MSSQL?" And so I took the time to answer that question, and you honor that by voting  my answer down and say you knew that. Thanks!